# SwiftUI View convenience initializers with `where` constraints

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols

I have a generic SwiftUI view that imitates the pattern of a ForEach or List, as follows:

```
struct SwiftUIView<T: RandomAccessCollection, ElementView: View, ID: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: T.Element
    let keyPath: KeyPath<T.Element, ID>
    let content: (T.Element) -> ElementView
    var data: T
    
    init(data: T, id: KeyPath<T.Element, ID>, selection: Binding<T.Element>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T.Element) -> ElementView) {
        ...
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data, id: keyPath) { element in 
           content(element)
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to create some convenience initializers to leverage the indices of RandomAccessCollections.

The following initializer that maps my collection type T to the indices of some array (`T == Array<Value>.Indices`) compiles without issue.

```
init<Value>(data: [Value], selection: Binding<Array<Value>.Index>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Array<Value>.Index, Value) -> ElementView)
where T == Array<Value>.Indices, ID == Array<Value>.Index {
    self.init(data: data.indices, id: \.self, selection: selection) { index in
        content(index, data[index])
    }
}
```

A similar initalizer which accepts a generic parameter `C: RandomAccessCollection` and maps T to C.Indices does not compile:

```
init<C: RandomAccessCollection>(data: C, selection: Binding<C.Index>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (C.Index, C.Element) -> ElementView)
where T == C.Indices, ID == C.Index {
    self.init(data: data.indices, id: \.self, selection: selection) { index in
        content(index, data[index])
    }
}
```

Note that the associated type Indices of a RandomAccessCollection also conforms to RandomAccessCollection.

On its face, it feels like this should work, as type `C` in the second initializer should act as a 1:1 stand-in for `Array<Values>` in the first initializer.

Wondering what I might be missing here, or if maybe the compiler is just not able to infer all the conformances here.

Answer (score 0):

The SwiftUI.ForEach does not use such initilizer, instead they specify explicitly for `Range<Int>`... but I think you need something like (main part snapshot):

```
init(data: T, selection: Binding<T.Element>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T.Element) -> ElementView) 
  where T.Element == ID {
```

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4 on

Complete [findings, code, and demo is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/View_convenience_initializers_constraints.md)

Comment: Well, Array<>.Indices is in fact Range<Int> , but I'm basically trying to generalize over that idea for all arbitrary RandomAccessCollections.  

Anyway, sorry if I framed the questions in terms of ForEach.  At its core, the question is about why the generic constraints aren't being satisfied here.